# Why is the number of arbitrary constants in the general solution of a system of ODE's the same as the number of unknown functions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Why is the number of arbitrary constants in the general solution of a system of first order ODE's the same as the number of unknown functions?
For example, the general solution of the system
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x+4y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=x-2y$$

is

$$x=4Ae^{2t}+Be^{-3t}$$
$$y=Ae^{2t}-Be^{-3t}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants.

But why do we need exactly 2 arbitrary constants for this solution to cover all possible particular solutions of the system?  $ $ Why is this number the same as the number of unknown functions?

Comment: Because the dimension of the space of solutions is 2.

Answer (score 2):

The collection of constants is equivalent to the set of initial values. The back-and-forth is governed by the Picard-Lindelöf theorem. Any first order system $y'=f(x,y)$ with sufficiently smooth $f$ has unique solutions provided an initial value. The parametrized form of the solution $y(t)=\phi(t;t_0,y_0)$ is called the flow.

If you have a solution form $y(t)=\psi(t,C)$, then translation from constants to initial value is given for any fixed $t_0$ by $y_0=\psi(t_0,C)$. If the set of parameters $C$ is minimal, this has to be locally bijective, so the dimension of $C$ s the same as the dimension of $y$. Obviously, the flow already has this form with $C=y_0$.

Comment: I see.  So, this means there's really no "simple" answer and I should take it as given until I've studied some more calculus and analysis.

Comment: @Stephen : Well, in the case of linear ODE it is that simple, as a solution $y(t)=\Phi(t)C$ leads to $y_0=\Phi(t_0)C$ so that the relation of parameters to initial points and thus the relation of the dimension reduces to the linear algebra properties of the matrix $\Phi(t_0)$.

Comment: Indeed, it seems the answer is simply because of the fact that to specify any particular solution, one needs an initial condition for each single one of the $n$ unknown functions.  Still, I'm not seeing the details of how this translates to exactly $n$ constants in the general solution.  I wouldn't be able to prove it for example, which is why I think I'll have to come back to it later. :- )